# Full-width, fixed-height video

Tags: wordpress, html, html5-video

I'd like to display a video on my WordPress site in between content, and I'd like that video to take up the full page width, and a fixed height. It's ok that the videos scales and crops as-needed.

I'd also prefer to stream it from YouTube, Vimeo, etc, as the site's performance is somewhat hindered when the video is self-hosted.

Have gotten closest to desired result using the YouTube IFrame player API. The actual container behaves the way I'd like, however the as soon as the video is played, the black bars appear on each side to maintain the video's aspect ratio.

Open to plug-ins and such.

Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[ARVE](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-responsive-video-embedder/) is a very popular and powerful plugin to display YouTube, Vimeo videos full screen.  It uses shortcodes to display videos in posts.